# creating a toggle function in emacs

Tags: function, emacs, transparency, toggle

How to get a function that toggles transparency for instance?
Possible candidates for the toggle could be, 0%, 85%, 100% or maybe just 2 of those...

```
    (defun transparency-toggle ()
    "Toggle transparency."
    (interactive)
    (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(alpha 85 50))
    )
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a ring version that lets you loop through various alpha, and jumps directly to the last or first alpha when called with a prefix argument:

```
(defun ring-transparency (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((ring '(100 50 25 0))
         (current (frame-parameter nil 'alpha))
         (last (car (last ring)))
         (next (if arg
                   (if (equal current (car ring)) last (car ring))
                 (or (cadr (member current ring)) (car ring)))))
    (set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha next)))
```

Comment: Best version. Thank you (I also adapted it for background color).

Answer (score 2):

The following code is taken from [Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransparentEmacs)

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))
(set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha '(100 100))

(defun toggle-transparency (unused)
  (interactive "P")
  (if (/=
       (cadr (frame-parameter nil 'alpha))
       100)
      (set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha '(100 100))
    (set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha '(85 50))))


(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") 'toggle-transparency)
```

EDIT: answering to your question. If you don't initialize a frame parameter `alpha` it will be nill. So, if you don't want to have the code:

```
(set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha '(100 100))
```

you can check it in the function toggle-transparency

```
(defun toggle-transparency (unused)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((curr-alpha (frame-parameter nil 'alpha)))
    (if (or (null curr-alpha) (/= (cadr curr-alpha) 100))
        (set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha '(100 100))
      (set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha '(50 50)))))
```

Comment: Somehow it didn't work with that "set frame parameter nil". What I had to do to make it work is use the code in my answer below.